# Testing if inside \halign

Tags: macros, tex-core

I am trying to write a macro that has a different behavior when called from text mode, math mode, display math, and math tables. The first three are easy enough with `\ifmmode` and `\mathchoice`. But the last one is a bit more complicated as I have to test for various LaTeX- and AMS-environments: `array`, `array*`, `gather`, `align` etc. However, as all those environments are implemented as variants of `\halign`, the cleanest way would be to check if the macro is called from within a `\halign`.

Hence my question: is there a way to test if a macro is called from `\halign` ?

(this is a user-level macro that will very probably never be called from inside `\noalign`, so no need to put an extra test for this case).

**Edit**: I found a quasi-answer to this, by which I mean that it works in all the above AMS environments but not in a plain `\halign`. Namely, in plain math, `\math@cr@@@` is a macro expanding to `\cr`, but it is changed in the aligned environments. So I only have to do something like

```
\def\plain@cr{\cr}
\ifx\math@cr@@@\plain@cr ... \else ... \fi
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you give an example of this macro and of what it should do in the various cases?

Comment: I'm trying to write for example a macro `\macro` such that `$$x \macro$$` expands to `x display` and `\begin{align} x \macro \end{align}` etc. expands to `x align`.

Comment: I tend to agree with @egreg that we need to know what you are after. Very likely there _is_ another solution to your real problem than testing for `\halign`. Usually you don't need to step so deep in TeX core.

Comment: Ok, would `\makeatletter\def\currentenvironment{\@currenvir}\makeatother` and then using `\currentenvironment` do the trick? Of course, you can't use `$$ ... $$` syntax, but that is obsolate in LaTeX anyways, in favour of `\[ ... \]`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe something like `\ifmmode\else\ifinner <now  in halign>\fi\fi`? (though it could be also in a `\hbox` then)

Comment: @morbusg `\ifinner` is true also between `\left` and `\right`, so it's unreliable for the OP's purpose.

Comment: There is no built-in flag for knowing whether TeX is inside `\halign`. However, I'm still thinking what such a four-pronged macro should do and why an alignment environment should be considered differently from displayed math.

Comment: @egreg: I think I remember I once did something for either a `\qed` or `\eq` (general eqno) -macro using `\ifinner` and I was able to use it in display math mode, normal math and in alignments, etc. Of course I cannot find it anywhere now, grrr.

Comment: @morbusg `\halign{#\cr\vbox{a\ifinner x\else y\fi}\cr}` will show “ay”.